# Composition of array functions

Tags: arrays, vba

I am concerned about composition of function that return arrays.

For example, let us define

```
Function APTranspose(X As Variant) As Variant

Dim v() As Variant
Dim r, c, rc, cc As Integer

r = X.rows.count
c = X.Columns.count

ReDim v(1 To c, 1 To r)

For cc = 1 To c
    For rc = 1 To r
    v(cc, rc) = X(rc, cc)
    Next
Next

APTranspose = v

End Function
```

and the useless function

```
Function Identity(X As Variant) As Variant

Dim res As Variant

res = APTranspose(X)

res = APTranspose(res)

Identity = res

End Function
```

Now it is clear that Function (x)  should be x itself.

However I get #VALUE! on Excel. In general, I cannot make composition of array functions. Why is that??

Thanks!

Comment: in which you call this function in Excel??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occurs because, when you call `APTranspose` in line `res = APTranspose(X)` it work ok, because `X` is object of `Range` type and it has properties like `X.rows.count` and `X.Columns.count`. But when you call this function in line `res = APTranspose(res)` - `res` it's not `Range` object, it's an Array, and it doesen't have properties `X.rows.count` and `X.Columns.count`. And this triggers an error.

You can use following code:

```
Function APTranspose(X As Variant) As Variant
    APTranspose = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(X)
End Function

Function Identity(X As Variant) As Variant
    Dim res As Variant
    res = APTranspose(X)
    res = APTranspose(res)
    Identity = res
End Function
```

**UPD:**

or you can use following functions:

```
Function APTranspose(X As Variant) As Variant
    Dim v() As Variant
    Dim r, c, rc, cc As Integer

    If TypeOf X Is Range Then
        r = X.Rows.Count
        c = X.Columns.Count
    Else
        r = UBound(X, 1)
        c = UBound(X, 2)
    End If
    ReDim v(1 To c, 1 To r)
    For cc = 1 To c
        For rc = 1 To r
        v(cc, rc) = X(rc, cc)
        Next
    Next
    APTranspose = v
End Function

Function Identity(X As Range) As Variant

    Dim res() As Variant

    res = APTranspose(X)
    res = APTranspose(res)
    Identity = res
End Function
```

Comment: So how can I retrieve the number of rows/columns for an array?

Comment: really? it works for me..what troubles have you had?